# Percona backup to different database name

Tags: linux, mysql, backup, percona

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL: How to backup and restore using different schema name using xtrabackup](https://serverfault.com/questions/320441/mysql-how-to-backup-and-restore-using-different-schema-name-using-xtrabackup)

I'm using percona backup tool `Xtrabackup` for backing up different MySQL server, right now I would like to setup another instance of database I have, but under different name, how can I do this?

This is what I have:

- host 1 is running database named A
- host 2 is running also database named A

and I would like to:

- setup database A copied from host 2 on on the host 1 but under name B

I'm running latest versions of mysql (5.5) and Xtrabackup